# From PyPi to Conda-Forge

Tags: python, cookiecutter, conda-forge

I used [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) to create a simple python package that I pushed to Pypi. Next I want to get the package into the Conda ecosystem and found the conda-forge channel really powerful. My only problem is that publishing to conda-forge requires a couple of manual steps including rewriting part of a meta.yaml file. Is there a better way to do this?

My current approach:

1. Create Conda Recipe (meta.yaml) using [Conda Skeleton](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html)
2. Fork [Conda Forge Staged Recipes](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes)
3. Manually edit some lines in the meta.yaml since conda skeleton recipe is
   slightly different than what is accepted by conda-forge.
4. Create a Pull Request for conda forge staged recipes.

Ideally I would like to sync pypi with conda-forge without any manual steps. This is probably not possible but suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no automated way to do this. Sounds like an opportunity for a Python package! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Another way without editing whatsoever is using [grayskull](https://github.com/conda-incubator/grayskull) !

Comment: I wrote the steps together on https://medium.com/@oliverzehentleitner/how-to-publish-a-pypi-package-on-conda-forge-e0fc8a094daf

Answer (score 2):

This is presently possible if you use a tool called [rever](https://regro.github.io/rever-docs/).  This will allow automatic releases to pypi and conda-forge for a library you own.  conda-forge uses this internally to release things like conda-smithy